# C# and SQL LIKE condition: '%' works as single-character wildcard

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wildcard, sql-like

I have query like that in my DataSet (database is located in .mdf file):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE SomeField LIKE @Param
```

Table `TableName` contains record **`Значение`** in `SomeField` field.

When `@Param` is **`Значени%`** it's works perfectly, but when `@Param` is **`Значен%`** or **`Значе%`**, it's returns 0 rows. **`Значе%%%`** also works.

Why  '%' works as single-character wildcard?

Comment: What is the collation of your table and database? Do you get the same results when running the query elsewhere?

Comment: And datatypes of `column` and `param` please.

Comment: Cyrillic General, in dataset viewer and c# code i got same results

Comment: `column` - char(255), `param` - ansi string

Comment: Do query 'SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE SomeField LIKE 'Значен%' works fine?

Comment: You sure you don't mean NCHAR?

Comment: @ohohoho - You shouldn't be using a fixed width 255 char column if that is at all typical of the data you are storing in it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you should be using @param of NVARCHAR, not NCHAR

```
declare @Param nchar(255)
set @Param = N'Значе%'
```

This is really

```
N'Значе%             ...' (many more spaces)
```

So it won't match your data, which is

```
N'Значение             ...' (padded with spaces)
```